# Enable https ssl in Ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, https

Good day, i tried to enable https secure connection for my rails application.
First of all, set config.force_ssl = true in application.rb only. So, re-started rails server, but there was error: "HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #

Comment: What Ruby app server are you using?  Puma, Thin, WEBrick, etc.?

Comment: @Joe, I am using Puma